# Powerapps cannot show some of the subfolders

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I was trying to access to subfolders and files in one folder, so I use Filter(DOCS,'Folder Path'="DOCS/Folder 1/Folder 2/"), but it only returns part of the subfolders in this folder, all the folder name marked with blue filling rectangles are missing.
[image]
Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: What's the total number of items in your library?

Comment: 10 subfolders and 13 files. Now I only ask to show subfolders and it only shows 7 out of 10.